# WebDriver: Extracting Xpath

Tags: xpath

Can anyone please let me know how to extract the Xpaths from a webpage using Selenium Webdriver. I woudn't want to use Firebug or any other tools, a piece of code should extract all the Xpaths in a given webpage.

Comment: Well if this could be done my friend most of us will not have a job. I am not sure this can be done. Why do you want to do it when it is so easy to write xpath?

Comment: What are you trying to do, what is the real intent? It's not particularly clear to me why you would want to use Selenium to exctract XPath expression of the elements on the page. What do you want to do with them afterwards?

Comment: This seems like an XY Problem - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible for a number of reasons. First and formost for any given XML document there are **infinite** XPaths for any given node.

Consider this XML document:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b/>
    </a>
    </c>
</root>
```

Simple enough, but lets look at element `<b>`. Below are some of the XPaths for it:

```
/root/a/b
/root/a[1]/b[1]
/root/*/b
/root//b
/root/a/*[1]
//b[count(ancestor::a) == 1]
```

Get the point? Which of these is the right one? XPaths are a way of describing one or more sets of elements in an XML document, based on a given condition. Without a known starting point, and a specific desired output there are unlimited ways to describe an element, thats why it is so powerful.

Comment: If the answer is helpful feel free to vote up as such, and accept this  answer if it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

The WebDriver doesn't do this for you, there's no included functionality for this.

If you really want it (and it definitely is possible and it's not *that* hard), you can write it yourself or adapt some of the existing solutions:

- [Firebug's source of its `Copy XPath` functionality](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/master/extension/content/firebug/lib/xpath.js#L19)
- [some random untested JS solution I found online](http://dzone.com/snippets/get-xpath)